# How to refer KML style inside TileMill

Tags: kml, tilemill

The following KML file contains paths with style and name tags: [example](http://www.skimap.org/data/1006/osm/kml/2011-12-28.kml).

```
<Folder>
          <name>Pedestrian</name>
          <Style id="style-Pedestrian">
            <LineStyle>
              <color>#ff808080</color>
              <width>3</width>
            </LineStyle>
          </Style>
          <Placemark id="">
            <styleUrl>#style-Pedestrian</styleUrl>
            <LineString>
              <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
              <coordinates>8.5950278,46.6329618,1 8.5951371,46.6329856,1 8.595266,46.6327811,1 8.5951712,46.6327501,1 8.5950278,46.6329618,1</coordinates>
            </LineString>
          </Placemark>
....
```

I tried to refer to the styles, but the TileMill does not recognize it. After I import the files and apply the style using "Carto styling language" the path just disappears.

Example:

```
#imported_id {
  [Name="Pedestrian"] {
    line-width:2;
    line-color:#000000;
  }
}

#imported_id {
  [Name="style-Pedestrian"] {
    line-width:2;
    line-color:#000000;
  }
}

#imported_id  #style-Pedestrian {   
      line-width:2;
      line-color:#000000;

  }
```

Why I can't refer to the styles inside the TileMill? Is it possible or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please check out http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/manual/adding-layers/ which explains KML support in TileMill. I hope it will help.

*KML is a standard geospatial data format that was popularized by Google with the Google Earth and Google Maps products. TileMill has limited support of KML – embedded styles will be ignored, and other features such as images, flythroughs, and 3D models are not supported. There is also no support for the compressed KMZ format at this time: to use a KMZ file, simply uncompress it as a zip file, and then use the resulting KML file.*

Comment: thanks for your answer, but according to this it works somehow :http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/tilemill/7070-style-individual-layers. I've read the documentation a few times :).

Comment: @flatronka Can you pass on the KML you loaded in Tilemill to style so i can give it a try on my system and come up with some solution?

Comment: thank you for your time, here is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27560194/example.kml

Comment: I will check and will get back to you ASAP :)

Comment: I have just managed to check and realize that problem is with KML file not with TileMill Styling (CartoCSS) to verify please open the kml in dropbox with Google Earth and go deep into MainFolder->Roads->Core->Pedestrain-> Here you will see two polylines with no name and thats the reason tilemill gets NULL in Name Column for these geometries. I hope it will help.